# Mystic forge - demote crafting materials?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So there's the formula for promoting crafting materials....  Can you do it in reverse?

Example to promote materials:

> Philosopher's Stone + Tier 2 Dust + Tier 2 Material + Tier 1 Material = Tier 2 material

Should promote Tiny Claws to Small Claws.

Can you do this -

> Philosopher's Stone + Tier 1 Dust + Tier 1 Material + Tier 2 Material ?= Tier 1 material?

To demote Claws into Small Claws?

Comment: I'd look through this right now, but I am currently at work. This might give you an answer: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crafting_material#List_of_crafting_materials

Comment: Not sure what to do with that link?  I added some text to try to make it clearer.
Ya, if I wasn't at work.... I'd try it, too. :)

Comment: The link is wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crafting_material By time I get home in 3 hours I'll test it out on the servers and let you know :)

Comment: I think it would be more economical to just sell the tier 2 material and buy the tier 1 material on the Trading Post.

Comment: @Brian You'd think so, but right now *everyone* wants Tier 1 crafting materials, so they're way more expensive than they should be. Jute scraps were going for ~27 CP yesterday, when the vendor price is 3 CP.

Comment: Exactly.
Not too long ago, you were able to get over 75 CP for the jute scraps.  Copper ore was going for around the same and it requires 10 to make an ingot.

Did anyone have a chance to try it?  I didn't realize it cost 50 items to transmute.... :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no formula that allows you to take higher level materials and demote them to lower level materials. The process is one way only, meaning these materials can only be promoted using the mystic forge.

The recipes for promoting materials can be found on the [Guild Wars 2 Wiki page for the Mystic Forge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Forge#Materials).